# UV map texture missing when edit the model

Tags: modeling, uv, image

I had a problem when I edited the model. and adjusted the UV, but when I spread out the UV, only the part where the UV was visible There are only hands and feet as shown in the picture I attached. (I fixed the whole body except the hands and feet which are still original)I've tried uploading it several times but it's still the same. Did I miss something here?
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please pack your images and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: From your image, looks like you need to activate Sync UV, it's the icon at the left of vertex selection icon (inside the UV editor) the icon is like two arrow

Comment: my link file
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=KxgadRy3" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/KxgadRy3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 slots in your material list, you've assigned the second slot to the body faces, and this slot is empty, if you want to assign the material that is assigned to the first slot, simply remove this second slot in *Object* mode:

[image]

Comment: wow it's work thank you ^_^